# Post on Multiple Friend's Wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an iPhone application, which needs to post some alert message on all my  facebook friends' wall. 
I am using FB Graph API SDK for iPhone, and can able to post message as batch request using FBGraph API. The code is as follows. I referred https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/ for this.

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"" withPostVars:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"[{\"method\":\"POST\",\"relative_url\":\"1846638186\/feed\",\"body\":\"message=test\"},{\"method\":\"POST\",\"relative_url\":\"1075291616\/feed\",\"body\":\"message=test\"}]", @"batch", nil]];
```

But this is not effective, as using this, we just can post message on 10 friend's wall, that is the maximum feed request limit allowed per day. If i attached 10 POST message in batch request, it's been treated as 10 FEED API CALLS. So limit exceeded in a single message to all my friends. Then, i cannot use this Graph API call to post message for next one day.

How can i resolve this issue?

Is there any way to use POST API call ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ ) for this, by just adding all friend's facebook ids in the parameter "TO"? 
Will it work or should i go for some other way?

Please advice, Thank you.

Comment: I think that is thought of as FB 'spam'